# Jenkins: Get build numbers range on a particular day

Tags: jenkins, build, scripting, automation

For data mining reasons, I want to get build numbers range of a jenkins job that were built on a particular day. Is there a plugin that accomplishes this or any other possible way?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in REST JSON API will give you a list of the builds for a particular job: `http://jenkins:8080/job/JOB_NAME/api/json?tree=builds[fullDisplayName,id,number,timestamp]&pretty=true`

Produces something like:

```
{
  "builds" : [
    {
      "fullDisplayName" : "JOB_NAME #113",
      "id" : "2014-10-31_23-05-20",
      "number" : 113,
      "timestamp" : 1414821920808
    },
    {
      "fullDisplayName" : "JOB_NAME #112",
      "id" : "2014-10-31_17-26-39",
      "number" : 112,
      "timestamp" : 1414801599000
    },
    ....
```

If your build ids are the basic date-stamp (as above), you can do a little string processing to filter the results. Otherwise, you can convert the timestamp to the appropriate date and filter on that.

Most Jenkins pages have a REST API link at the bottom that provides more documentation, though you often need to experiment with the API to figure out what details it can provide.

---

*Update*: As @Nick discovered, the `builds` result is limited to the latest 100 elements by default. According to [this Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22977), you can use the hidden `allBuilds` element to retrieve "all builds". So if you need *all* builds, use: `http://jenkins:8080/job/JOB_NAME/api/json?tree=allBuilds[fullDisplayName,id,number,timestamp]&pretty=true`

Jenkins 1.568 also introduced pagination in the API results, so it's possible to retrieve results by range. The Jenkins REST API link describes the syntax if your Jenkins version supports it.

Comment: This kinda helps as i can do the string processing. However, I am looking for certain date range. This only generates the last array for last 100 builds. Say, I want to get this data for last 1000 builds, how do i generate the URL?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Global Stats Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin)

Which also has a [JSON REST API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=46336030)