# How do I get a list of builds from Jenkins that have been running in the past 24 hours?

Tags: jenkins

So I know how to get a list of the current running jobs from Jenkins:
[From Jenkins, how do I get a list of the currently running jobs in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843874/from-jenkins-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-currently-running-jobs-in-json)

Is there a way to get a list of all the jobs which have ran on Jenkins within the last 24 hours?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to get Jenkins to perform the date filtering for you. 
So this approach is similar to a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26725325/172599).

You can get a list of all jobs and builds with a query like: `http://jenkins:8080/api/json?tree=jobs[name,builds[fullDisplayName,id,number,timestamp]]&pretty=true`

Then use the `id` or `timestamp` field to filter for builds generated after your target date.

Comment: That is currently how I am doing it, but I hoped there was a better way. It seems like it should be simple enough to add something like exclude= to the URL query to exclude any builds which do not have a timestamp within the range I am looking for. I've done something similar to exclude builds which contain a prefix like MOD_. However, I seem to be doing it wrong here.